# C Functions: static or remove from header

Tags: c, function, static, header

[Ansi-C/Eclipse]
For some reason I did not find anything helpful so here is my Question:

I want `bar()` to be only accessible to code inside `foobar.c`

Should I:

- put static in front of the declaration and the definition
- remove the declaration of `bar()` from `foobar.h` and put it in `foobar.c`?

What is the difference? This is my setup:

main.c:

```
#include "foobar.h"

int main() {
    foo();
}
```

foobar.h:

```
#ifndef FOOBAR
#define FOOBAR

void foo();
void bar();     //Move to foobar.c?

#endif
```

foobar.c:

```
#include "foobar.h"

void foo() {
    bar();
}
void bar() {    //make this static?
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're absolutely right. You should do both.

- making a function `static` limits the visibility of that function to the translation unit (file) only. That function cannot be called from any other function present in any other *source file*.
- You don't need to call a `static` function from some other translation unit, hence you don't need a prototype in header file. If required, you can put a forward declaration inside `foobar.c` itself.

Comment: Why would I make it `static` if it can not be called from outside anyways? Or is there another way to call it?

Comment: @BMicraft without `static` linkage, you __can__ call the function if you know the function prototype. With `static`, you _can't_.